# Angular 8 ajax slow at some times

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-httpclient

Following a tutorial, I have this ajax request.

```
merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
  .pipe(
    startWith({}),
    switchMap(() => {
      this.isLoadingResults = true;
      console.log('ajax start')
      console.time('ajax')
      return this.usersService.getUsers({
        sort: this.sort.active,
        order: this.sort.direction,
        page: this.paginator.pageIndex + 1
      });
    }),
    map((data: UsersList) => {
      console.log('ajax end')
      console.timeEnd('ajax')
      this.isLoadingResults = false;
      this.resultsLength = data.count;
      data.users.map(user => {
        user.totalTime = moment('2015-01-01')
          .startOf('day')
          .seconds(+user.totalTime)
          .format('HH:mm:ss');
        return user;
      });
      return data.users;
    }),
    catchError(() => {
      this.isLoadingResults = false;
      return observableOf([]);
    })
  )
  .subscribe(data => (this.users = data));
```

running and testing on local machine, this works great.
But when I access it using my mobile phone which is connected to the same local network, ajax some times takes about 5 seconds to load.

[image]

As you can see in the image, mostly it loads fast, but there are times that it took 5 seconds to load.
I'm using `mat-table` by the way.

In the same image, you can see that the server did response in just very much less than a second.
So, I'm thinking there is delay that I do not know of.

Comment: Are you sure this is `http` issue? It is possible that mobile phone is taking long time too render the same data?

Comment: Also, whats the size of data you are receiving ?

Comment: Not really sure where is the issue.. that's why I asked, hoping to find a clue at least.. the table is just plane table. The size of the data is in the screenshot, just around 400B which takes about 29ms to load. that screenshot is a remote debugging for android. So, everything in the screenshot is from my mobile phone.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is between `switchMap` and `map`, but don't know what.

Comment: How do you load material libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Like any issues to do with performance, profile your code using the Chrome developer tools.

Under the Audits tab and run some performance audits on it.

Under the Performance tab start a new recording and reload the page.

If you see any spikes in the graphs, you may have a performance issue. However, if you only see a long wait time between requests, then it's just a networking issue.